# PrimeFaces LazyDataModel advanced filters

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using PrimeFaces `LazyDataModel` and it's working fine. However, I need to add some advanced filters in my Facelets page. I don't want to use the PrimeFaces native filter, with the filters in the table header. I need advanced filters in a form, and a 'search' button for searching, using the features of primefaces lazy pagination.

Can I do this? Is there a way to call the 'load' method in my search button using my advanced filters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Load' method is called every time on update.
You can add ArrayList of filters for your implementation of lazy model and use them in 'load' method

Comment: Please add a more specific example. Where use the 'Load' method?